# EF6 DB first mapping weak entities

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have the following structure in SQL:

```
    Question
    -----------
    questionId  | PK
    description

    Channel
    -----------
    channelId   | PK
    description
```

And a weak map with a composite key:

```
    QuestionChannel
    ---------------
    channelId   | PK
    questionId  | PK
```

When I create a data model in Vis Studio using Entity Framework the weak entity map (QuestionChannel) is not created. Instead a many to many relationship is shown in the designer. How can I force EF to model this object? Would there be any disadvantage to swapping the composite key for a redundant primary key?:

```
    QuestionChannel
    ---------------
    id          | PK
    channelId
    questionId
```

Comment: Why do you want to force EF to include the join table?

Comment: Basically this is part of a DB migration. The destination DB has different foreign key so I am writing an application to map the FK's between the 2 data contexts (source and destination DB's) I need to populate 'QuestionChannel' however it does not exist as an entity in the DB context.

Comment: by default if it's a join table (a table than only contains composite FK, PK), EF will not include it. You can still manage the relationship by directly add to the collection, if A and B are many to many, A will have Bs collection property, and B will have As collection property

Comment: That makes sense, just had a play around in EF, populated a static list of 'Questions' and if I add a 'Channel' and provide a collection of questions it adds to the map table. Thank you, much appreciated.